# Twitter4j - FilterQuery on multiple languages

Tags: java, twitter4j

I have an application which fetches Twitter posts using a FilterQuery object (Twitter4j).
It is possible to set properties as the keywords and the language of the wanted posts in this way:

```html
FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery().track(keyWords);
query.language("en");
TwitterStream twitterStream.filter(query);
```

What if I wanted to pass an array of languages like `String [] lang = {"en", "fr", "es", "it"}`instead of just passing a single language?
Is it possible?
PS: I have already checked [this question](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjI3KTa66bUAhULshQKHalmB6oQFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22249393%2Ftwitter4j-query-on-different-languages&usg=AFQjCNFqNyD7nEcYAZX4Ugn6lspCHeSBsg), but it just works around the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add several parameters by adding them between `""` and separating them by commas. It works.